# Data input for MX records in DYNDNS

Tags: email, dns, mail-server

I am trying to add new MX records from google which provide the following data:
1- Priority
2- Host Alias
3- Value and destination

The problem is that there is nothing to add to the DATA filed in add DNS Record as shown in the screenshot in the attachments.
Can you kindly guide me to what to put there?

[image: google mx records]
[image: dydns adding mx records and data invalid error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enter the `priority value` received from google in `Data` field.
Like `10 mail.example.com`

Comment: it gives me invalid data too.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add `priority`. The correct value for `Data` field is like `10 mail.example.com`

Comment: the value was accepted in the DATA form. Although Google Verification failed for some reason, this answered my question correctly. Thank you so much.